# is it possible to get the tooltip while hovering the canvas element?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

i have an canvas image for analog clock

i need to show the tool tip for second needle, hour needle and minute needle. But all of them are in single canvas image..

actually the element renders as like below in the html

```
<div id="circularframe" class="">
<div id="Analog clock">
<canvas role="presentation" width="500" height="360"></canvas>
</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible in canvas element...

Answer (score 0):

if you have just started then i would recommend using Kineticjs link is [here](http://kineticjs.com/) , where you can do lots of interesting stuff with canvas which includes labels too check this tutorial [here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-label-tutorial/) for getting lables/tooltip on canvas with kinetic js. Hope it helps
alternatively with Jquery you may have to some extra work , you can do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/yLBjM/) , for example in this example we add text like:

```
dots.push({
        x: getXPixel(data.values[i].X),
        y: getYPixel(data.values[i].Y),
        r: 4,
        rXr: 16,
        color: "red",
        tip: "#text" + (i + 1)
    });
```

Hope it helps